# Is correct the code for "Bring To Front" or "Send To Back"?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Is correct the below code for "Bring To Front" or "Send To Back" a field/object in VBA Access 2010?

My code is:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

If IsOpen("Details_ME") Then

    Me.Controls("DRAFT_Logo").InSelection = True
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdBringToFront
Else

    Me.Controls("DRAFT_Logo").InSelection = True
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSendToBack

End If

End sub
```

VBA shows yellow error on below code:

```
Me.Controls("DRAFT_Logo").InSelection = True
```

Any help or advice is appreciated

Comment: The yellow highlight only means that's the current executing line, it's not an error by itself, it's just a feature of the debugger - what's the *actual* error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a little correction and it was useful, So it works properly :)

I Should put the codes into the "Current Event" Instead the "Load Event".

```
Private Sub Report_Current()

If IsOpen("Details_ME") Then

    Me.Controls("DRAFT_Logo").InSelection = True
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdBringToFront

Else

    Me.Controls("DRAFT_Logo").InSelection = True
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSendToBack

End If

End Sub
```

Thank You ...